# Get oozie job information in oozie workflow

Tags: shell, hadoop, oozie

By using the below command on command line, we get the job details of the oozie job even though it is still under progress.

```
export OOZIE_URL=http://..../oozie
oozie job -info 0177204-172227110941438-oozie-oozi-W
```

There is oozie workflow running, in the last shell action I am trying to capture job information details in to a file.

```
job.sh
------------
job_id=${1}

export OOZIE_URL=http://..../oozie
oozie job -info job_id >> /tmp/job_id.txt
```

But the above command is not working. Is there a way, how we can get the job information details within the oozie job which is running, and store it in text file.

Comment: _"script is not working"_ > what does that mean? Do you get an Oozie error, a shell syntax error in the YARN log for the Action? Or is it just that you don't know where to find the file that was created on a random cluster node?

Comment: The script is working except for the command "oozie job -info $job_id >> /tmp/job_id.txt"  and it is not throwing any error. When I do cat to the file, it is empty. Where as other statements are working in the script.

Comment: Did you try to capture `stderr` also? Did you check the YARN log for shell syntax errors (e.g. Oozie client not installed on that node, or not in the PATH set by YARN, or whatever)? In other words, have you done any kind of basic debugging??

Comment: I checked YARN log too, there was no syntax error, it completely ignored that statement. The remaining statements messages were captured except that.

Answer (score 3):

I hope you are running your command on a cluster from where you have access to fetch info/kill/start oozie job. If that is the case then your command should work fine. I tried below commands and I was able to see the results.

```
cluster:~$ oozie job -info job-id -oozie http://gateway-url/oozie/ > a.txt
cluster:~$ cat a.txt
```

The output was :

```
Job ID : job-id
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Workflow Name : workflow-name
App Path      : hdfs://path/to/workflow.xml
Status        : RUNNING
Run           : 0
User          : user-id
Group         : -
Created       : 2018-07-05 22:30 GMT
Started       : 2018-07-05 22:30 GMT
Last Modified : 2018-07-06 05:17 GMT
Ended         : -
CoordAction ID: coordinator-id@410

Actions
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID                                        Status    Ext ID                    Ext Status                  Err Code
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
job-id@:start:                            OK        -                         OK                           -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
job-id@action1                            OK        -                         action2                      -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
job-id@action2                            OK        -                         OK                           -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
job-id@action3                            OK        -                         action4                      -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
job-id@action4                            OK        MR_job_id1                SUCCEEDED                    -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
job-id@action5                            OK        MR_job_id2                SUCCEEDED                    -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
job-id@action6                            OK        -                         action7                      -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
job-id@action7                            OK        MR_job_id3                SUCCEEDED                    -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
job-id@action8                            OK        MR_job_id4                SUCCEEDED                    -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
job-id@action9                            RUNNING   MR_job_id5                RUNNING                      -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This will work I know.. The command is wrapped in shell script which is triggered within oozie workflow, then it is not working. We get empty file

Comment: so are you trying to get the info of the same job which has one of the action as the shell script running this command?

Comment: Yes.. Say I have 10 actions in 1 workflow. When I reach 10th action, it must capture all the 9 application id's of the current job within oozie.

Comment: @a123, did you get a solution for this? I want to get start time of current workflow in shell action.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure you have checked the results on the right node in the cluster? You can upload it to the HDFS for easy access:

   ```
   hadoop fs -put /tmp/job_id.txt /tmp
   # and then
   hadoop fs -cat hdfs:///tmp/job_id.txt
   ```
2. You can collect more debug data, if you run `oozie job` with `-debug` option. Then check, if an url generated by Oozie is correct (e.g. by pasting it to the browser). Maybe there is something wrong with your Oozie url?
3. Validate, if your input parameter (job id) for the shell script is set correctly. To get access to job id in your Oozie workflow you can use `${wf:id()}`.